# Change font colour on dark variant of Elementary theme

Tags: release-loki, themes

I am looking for a dark theme for Elementary OS Loki. I couldn't find anything better than the default theme with dark variant, but it has one problem: when I switch to categorized app view in menu, the categories are displayed with grey font, and they are barely visible. Is there any way I can change this font colour? I tried looking in `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0` without any luck so far. Also, if You know any good dark theme, I'd be glad to know.